# Making and pre-shebanging scripts, running into unwanted effect

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program to automate the creation of a Python script, with the option to create in its own folder.
Pseudocode looks as follows:
-Get file name to use
-Get user's choice for folder creation
-Make sure the current working directory is the one this script is running in (For good measure)
-If the user wants a folder made, mkdir with the same name as the file to be made and cd into it.
-Make a file with the requested name, chmod +x it, and insert the shebang line.

Actual code looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import stat
import sys
filename=sys.argv[1]
makefolder=bool(sys.argv[2])   #This might be where the error occurs?
def makeexec(fname):
    f=open(fname,'w+')
    f.write("#!/usr/bin/python3")
    f.close()
    st=os.stat(fname)
    os.chmod(fname,st.st_mode|stat.S_IXUSR|stat.S_IXGRP|stat.S_IXOTH)
os.chdir('/home/pi/programs')                  #^^^ effectively chmod +x
if makefolder:
    os.mkdir(filename)
    os.chdir('./'+filename)
makeexec(filename)
```

The code is called from the terminal as follows:

```
./pymake examplescript 1
```

1, 0, true, or false can be inserted in the second argument. True makes a folder, False does not.
The problem with this code is that it will make a folder regardless of the user's choice.

Comment: How do you call your script, maybe you are missunderstanding how `bool` works. Please check it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool)!

Comment: Please, add an example of input. How do you call your script ?

Comment: Daniel Luz got it, I just don't know how `bool()` works.

Comment: `bool()` transform your input to the value `True` or `False`. Verify the right command to create a folder, it should be also in the `sys` or in the `os`package.

Comment: Silgon, the program makes folders and files just fine.

Comment: (BTW, consider using the "Add an Answer" button to answer your own questions; editing answers into question text [is strictly disallowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387723/answer-a-question-inside-the-question), and policy for people observing questions that contain answers in their text [is to edit and remove them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)).